# Can't Fetch Table in Java

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc

I am very new to database since it's my first attempt to connect database with java but it shows me an error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I don't know why it's showing me this error although I've created a table of student in SQL and I can make queries on it but Net beans it throws an error that the table doesn't exist , What should I do now ?

Here is SQL CLI [image] shows that i have a table of student

Here is my java code

```
try
       {
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 

           Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","password");  

            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from student");  
                while(rs.next())  
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));

                con.close(); 
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           { 
               System.out.println(e);
           }
```

Comment: You are connecting to the `SYSTEM` schema/user. Are you sure that the `student` table is declared under `SYSTEM`? Normally you have a separate schema for your "user tables".

Comment: Yes might be there but whats the issue not fetching table ?

Comment: How do you connect to the DB with SQLPlus when you see the table correctly?

Comment: using connect command

Comment: Yes, obviously, but using which user id?